# Copy line if any cells in column are present in named range COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, countif, named-ranges

Very new to VBA but really need help on this code.

So, I'd like to copy any cells in Column L in Worksheet1, IF the name is in my named range (in Lookuptab sheet).

So far I have the code for the copy and paste and it works fine but since putting in the `countif` criteria, I get the error `compile error sub function not defined`

Please help!

Thanks,

My code is as follows:

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If CountIf(Sheets("Lookup").Range("Vendor_Lookup"), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 12).Value) > 0 Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`

Answer (score 0):

`CountIf` is not native to VBA. You have to access the worksheet function via

`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(......`

---

### A couple other notes:

1. No need to `Activate` anything per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. Copying/pasting inside a loop can be time consuming. Consider using a `Union` to collect target rows
3. Instead of using `CountIf`, you could use `Range.Find` to stick with native VBA functions

Combining all of this yields something like below:

```
Sub SHELTER_IN_PLACE()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim Target As Range, Found As Range

lr = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    Set Found = Sheets("Lookup").Range("Vendor_Lookup").Find(ws1.Range("A" & i))

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                Set Target = Union(Target, ws1.Range("A" & i))
            Else
                Set Target = ws1.Range("A" & i)
            End If
        End If

    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

If Not Target Is Nothing Then
    lr = ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```